# How to prevent tree 'cookies' from splitting?

Tags: green-wood

I have just been given several tree 'cookies' (cross sections of trunk or branches) that my wife wants to use in her crafts.  These include some of ash and birch, several around 3" diameter and a few larger ones maybe 10" diameter.  I'm worried that these will crack/split like the Liberty Bell as the wood dries out.  (I've seen that in the past with other tree cookies, although not of these two hardwoods.)

Is there something I can use to "fix" these tree slices so that they won't split?

Comment: Generally, no.  But you might want to have a listen to this: https://www.popularwoodworking.com/afterlife-of-trees/episode-1-trees-are-weird

Comment: What are your plans for finishing the end result? There are things like PEG, but they aren't necessarily compatible with some finishing.

Comment: No idea on finishing yet.  My wife wants to make crafts that will sit on top of the 'cookies', like little cactus arrangements with ceramic figurines and such.  So I am open to suggestions for ways to seal and finish them.

Comment: I know it's frowned upon here because links expire, but ... http://www.rockler.com/polyethylene-glycol-peg-green-wood-stabilizer and especially the technical info: http://go.rockler.com/tech/RTD10000%20812.pdf . If someone had the time to write this as an answer, I'd upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Aloysius, PEG is probably what you want to use here - you need to soak the cookie in PEG for a certain period of time (depending on the size/thickness of the cookie). There are charts available online that will help you determine how long this period will be - but it's a reasonably long period of time.

An alternative is a commercial product called Pentacryl.  Pentacryl works similarly to PEG, but at a much faster rate - typically an overnight soak is sufficient, instead of the weeks (or months) sometimes required with PEG.

Comment: funny, I did an amazon search for PEG and apparently it's also a laxative

Comment: @joe haha yup. the other laxative commonly used in woodworking is good old plain mineral oil - great for chopping boards *and* cleaning bowels!